# How to enable/disable clickable in kmllayer after display

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a google map that has a kml layer

```
kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url, {
    suppressInfoWindows: false, 
    preserveViewport: true,
    map:map,
    zindex: 0
});
```

I already know that by adding `clickable: false` to the list of options, I can make the layer non-clickable.

Can you do this "after the fact"?

Here's the scenerio.
I have a clickable kml on a google map.  It has a series of polygons.  I want to click a polygon, in which will disable the "clickable" setting of the kml, and overlay a second kml on top of the first.  The second kml is then clickable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to set the `clickable` option to false, call `kmlLayer.setOptions({clickable:false});`

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehhfco31/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var georssLayer

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=zrvhKWbQZI6E.kyr3RvQ9DprE&amp;lid=zrvhKWbQZI6E.kNpsmD-YyCYc'
  });
  georssLayer.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(georssLayer, 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = georssLayer.getStatus();
  });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="georssLayer.setOptions({clickable:false});" value="clickable:false" />
```